# How to add sql query varible into javascript and calculate?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm making a patient system with calculating the age of patient base on their birthday, but i'm getting error when I add it

Javascript:

```
<script>  
    var dob = new Date("06/24/2008");  <!-- I wanted to add {{ patient.birth }} into the date part-->
    //calculate month difference from current date in time  
    var month_diff = Date.now() - dob.getTime();  
      
    //convert the calculated difference in date format  
    var age_dt = new Date(month_diff);   
      
    //extract year from date      
    var year = age_dt.getUTCFullYear();  
      
    //now calculate the age of the user  
    var age = Math.abs(year - 1970);  
      
    //display the calculated age  
    document.write("Age of the date entered: " + age + " years");  
</script>
```

And {{ patient.birth }} is the sql query that I wanted to add into the script.

Comment: you are sending a post request? or you are using a  javascript client for your request?

Comment: No, I'm actually using the time of now to subtract birth date and get the user's age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var birthdate = $("#birth").val();
```

or

```
var birthdate = "{{ birth }}"
```

Depending on how the value is being implemented in the jinja.
Let me know which one works for you situation if you could.
I've done this in the past using both of these methods.

note: it's not by accident I'm leaving the "patient." out. This is intentional.

If they are changing the birthdate value on this screen.
Then you need to make an onchange event.
For example:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        function makeChange() {
            var birthdate = $("birth").val();
        }
    </style>
</head>

<form method="POST" action="">
    <div onchange="makeChange()">
        {{ patient.birth }}
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Argument passed to Date constructor should be in correct format.
In your case patient.birth should be string just like in your example: "06/24/2008".

You can not say like so:

```
const date = new Date("3 1930");
```

It prints

> Invalid Date

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_date_object.htm